# Featured image not showing on facebook share

Tags: facebook, social-sharing, sharing

I Guys! I´ve spent the whole morning after this...

Some post images are not showing up on facebook if I try to share.
But some are.

If I go to facebook and try to share:
http://www.taiff.com.br/taiffmag/2018/11/22/ariane-ianicelli-a-beauty-artist-que-vai-te-inspirar/

Everything works fine.

BUT, if I try to share this other post:
http://www.taiff.com.br/taiffmag/2018/11/08/4-penteados-taiff-curves/

The featured image doesnt shows up.

All og: tags are the same on both pages.

If I go to Facebook debugger, they identify both images.

The first one:
[image]

The second one:
[image]

I´ve searched SO and Google, but all answers are pointing to invalidate facebook cache (already did it). But that doesnt solved my problem.

Any other sugestion?

Thx a lot!

Comment: This is sometimes caching, try sharing with a query-param to bust the cache, ie: share: `wordpress.stackexchange.com?1=1` instead of just `wordpress.stackexchange.com` & that could be enough to job facebook's memory & get the image to load.

Comment: :( nope... it doesnt work either... I´ve tried to share: http://www.taiff.com.br/taiffmag/2018/11/20/tirando-duvidas-cabelos-loiros/?1=1 but same results... no image for me...